# How to escape double quotes in a parameter in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline parameter called myArray:
with following structure:

```
[
 { 
   “Mapping“: “{ “sourceCol“: “ColA“ }“
   “AnotherProperty“: 1
 }
]
```

How can I escape the double quotes around sourceCol and ColA. As it seems that ADF is adding automatically a / to them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure data Factory escape character and quote issue - copy activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593352/azure-data-factory-escape-character-and-quote-issue-copy-activity)

Answer (score 1):

In Azure data factory, backslash / appears wherever double quotes are used.

To avoid it, you can use replace() function to replace double quotes from the string or convert it to JSON.

You can check similar links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295103/preventing-azure-data-factory-adding-escape-character-to-xml/71307865#71307865) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095530/trouble-accessing-json-from-web-api-call-in-adf-and-inserting-in-sql-table/72128255#72128255) for reference.